# Is it possible to access the $request variable inside the Request class in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, validation, request

When i make a validation inside the Controller like in the following Laravel example:

`Validator::make($request->all(), [ 'credit_card_number' => 'required_if:payment_type,cc' ]);`

I can easily access the $request because I'm inside the controller method. However, I've noticed that using custom Request classes is considered a best practice in Laravel. I have a question regarding this: Is it possible to access the request variable inside the Request class?

Comment: Why do you need this? And can't you just use `$this` inside the your class?

Comment: I made same tests, and i realized that i can access the object utilizing $this, what make sense because $this is a object of the request class.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible , and it is simple to access request inside Request class.

Your Request class :

```
 public function rules()
{
    $paymentType1 = $this->request->input('payment_type');
    //OR 
    $paymentType2 = $this->input('payment_type');

    return [
        'credit_card_number' => 'required_if:payment_type,cc',
    ];
}
```

Comment: Ok i understood, thank you.